# append to file in tizen

Tags: filesystems, append, tizen

I create test.txt with this code:

=====================

```
function e(arg){
    if (typeof arg === "function") {
        return arg;
    } else {
        return function (er) { console.log('[' + arg + '] ' + er); };
    }
}

function rs(dir) {
            var fh  = dir.createFile(" test.text");
            {
                fh.openStream('rw', function(fs){
                    fs.write("Hello ");
                    fs.close();
                }, e('openStream'), 'UTF-8');
            }
        }

tizen.filesystem.resolve('downloads', rs, e('resolve'), 'rw');
```

=====================

And try to append some text by this code :

=====================

```
function append(dir) {
            var fh  = dir.resolve(" test.text");
            {
                fh.openStream('a', function(fs){
                    fs.write("  Tizen   .. ");
                    fs.close();
                }, e('openStream'), 'UTF-8');
            }
        }
tizen.filesystem.resolve('downloads', append, e('resolve'), 'a');
```

====================

but file contain only  last text ('Tizen  ..').

how to solve this problem?

thanks

Comment: samsung : The Filesystem apis are specific to target setup. 

They will not work with emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. It worked in my case.

```
var newDir, newFile;
tizen.filesystem.resolve("documents", function(dir) {
  newDir = dir.createDirectory("newDir");
  newFile = newDir.createFile("newFilePath.txt");
  newFile.openStream(
    "w",
    function(fs) {
      fs.write("Hello");
      fs.close();
    },
    function(e) {
      console.log("Error " + e.message);
    }, "UTF-8");
});

var text2;

tizen.filesystem.resolve("documents", function(dir) {
  file = dir.resolve("newDir/newFilePath.txt");

  file.openStream(
    "a",
    function(fs) {
      fs.write('Tizen .. ');
    },
    function(e) {
      console.log("Error " + e.message);
    }, "UTF-8");


  file.openStream(
    "r",
    function(fs) {
      text2 = fs.read(file.fileSize);
      fs.close();
      console.log(text2);
    },
    function(e) {
      console.log("Error " + e.message);
    }, "UTF-8");
});
```

Note: Please check in your project's config.xml file whether you've added the following privileges or not.

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/filesystem.read"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/filesystem.write"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is a bug in tizen emulator.

Comment: Not at all, it's also working in emulator in my case.

Comment: TV emulator 2.4 ?

Comment: No, Mobile 2.4.